# Threading Error BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa

For some reason my application is crashing and I'm not sure what's causing the problem other than it seems to be related to a dispatch queue I'm spanning when processing files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000038

VM Regions Near 0x38:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001018e7000-000000010190b000 [  144K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Desktop/MaviÃÅ 10.8 Build.app/Contents/MacOS/MaviÃÅ

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c83dc28 dispatch_async_f + 3
1   com.larod.mavi                  0x00000001018f6e12 0x1018e7000 + 65042
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff890df99e -[NSTableView performDragOperation:] + 215
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88f2c94f NSCoreDragReceiveMessageProc + 1651
4   com.apple.HIServices            0x00007fff8a8f046a DoMultipartDropMessage + 301
5   com.apple.HIServices            0x00007fff8a8f0135 DoDropMessage + 49
6   com.apple.HIServices            0x00007fff8a8f0c5e CoreDragMessageHandler + 1543
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89ca858d __CFMessagePortPerform + 701
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89bbcd09 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89bbca49 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 153
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89befc02 __CFRunLoopRun + 1826
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89bef0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8871beb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8871bc52 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8871bae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88bdb533 _DPSNextEvent + 685
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88bdadf2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88bd21a3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88b76bd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff85ff97e1 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8404a6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c8bdf1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c8bdce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c8a8191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8404ad16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c83fdea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c83f9ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8404a0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c8bffb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8761b2a1 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 689
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8761afd7 startIOThread(void*) + 148
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c8bb772 _pthread_start + 327
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c8a81a1 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fc1a0434f90  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0xffff803e5fbcafaf  rdx: 0x00007fff8c840ef2
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007fc1a0434f90  rbp: 0x00007fff5e317000  rsp: 0x00007fff5e316f58
   r8: 0xffff803e5fbcafaf   r9: 0x00000000000000ff  r10: 0x00007fc1a100ec00  r11: 0x0000000005d414ad
  r12: 0x00007fff8602d360  r13: 0x00007fc1a0435050  r14: 0x00007fc1a0435050  r15: 0x00007fff8602df50
  rip: 0x00007fff8c83dc28  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000038
Logical CPU: 0

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 2
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 28757
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=187.9M resident=78.8M(42%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=109.1M(58%)
Writable regions: Total=155.6M written=3596K(2%) resident=14.4M(9%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=141.2M(91%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CG backing stores                  2280K
CG image                              4K
CG raster data                       56K
CG shared images                   1184K
CoreAnimation                        44K
CoreImage                             4K
CoreServices                       1724K
IOKit                              4476K
IOKit (reserved)                      4K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC                            114.6M
MALLOC guard page                    48K
Memory tag=240                        4K
Memory tag=242                       12K
Memory tag=251                        8K
OpenCL                                8K
OpenGL GLSL                        1936K
OpenGL GLSL (reserved)              128K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
SQLite page cache                    96K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              9752K
VM_ALLOCATE                        16.2M
__DATA                             37.2M
__IMAGE                             528K
__LINKEDIT                         54.5M
__TEXT                            133.4M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                        41.9M
shared memory                       372K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             476.4M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    476.3M
```

This is the actual code that I believe is crashing the app.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), ^{
        unsigned long __block current = 0;
        unsigned long total = 0;

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _fileOperation = YES;
            [_fileCopyProgress setHidden:NO];
            [_fileCopyProgress startAnimation:self];
            [_processString setStringValue:@"Scanning..."];
            [_processString setHidden:NO];
        });

        for (NSURL* url in pboardObjects) {
            [self scanFileURLSForImport:url];
        }

        total = _mediaFileURLSForImport.count;
        [self updateImportProcess:current of:total];

        [_processString setStringValue:@"Importing..."];

        for (NSURL* url in _mediaFileURLSForImport) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(createVideo_2:) withObject:url waitUntilDone:YES];
            [self updateImportProcess:(++current) of:total];
        }

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(saveAction:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        [_tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selectImportedFiles:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _fileOperation = NO;
            [_processString setStringValue:@""];
            [_processString setHidden:YES];
            [_fileCopyProgress setHidden:YES];
            [_fileCopyProgress stopAnimation:self];
        });
    });
```

To add a bit of a twist, this crash doesn't happen on my test machine everything runs perfectly there, the app was submitted to the app store and approved by apple, meaning that it was tested in both regular and guest accounts. But yesterday it crashed everytime on a colleagues machine. The only thing I have to tried to solve it is this report from his machine. I can't replicate this on my test machine, everything works there.

Answer (score 3):

[Symbolicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) your crash report. After that you will see  part of the stack with your code which is involved in the crash.

```
1   com.larod.mavi                  0x00000001018f6e12 0x1018e7000 + 65042
```

Answer (score 0):

hook up lldb and set up exception break points to break at where you crashes, and check you stack trace by bt command in lldb. Usually, you got memory crash by writing to memories which is only readable, or you are accessing objects which are deallocated. From the log, I assume you are dragging Views and do something, are you sure the related views still valid in the block? all views should be on main thread and still valid in memory

Comment: To add a bit of a twist, this crash doesn't happen on my test machine everything runs perfectly there, the app was submitted to the app store and approved by apple, meaning that it was tested in both regular and guest accounts. But yesterday it crashed everytime on a colleagues machine. The only thing I have to tried to solve it is this report from his machine. I can't replicate this on my test machine, everything works there.

Comment: this happens a lot on other machines, what is the machine model and os version? try it with same model and os version, or you could borrow the machine to debug?

Comment: Is actually a new machine, he has a mac pro, the newer model, i do my dev stuff on a macbook pro and my test machine is a mac mini. I will try next weekend again, this bug is so unusual. Is hard to symbolicate without having his machine but I'll do my best.

Comment: you all on 10.10? it is rare, and I checked your memory info, I still suspect you have a memory leak. Did you get any core dump from the mac pro? try search google the location and find the core dump, it is all you need

Comment: I will try your suggestion, I'll save some dumps from the machine this weekend to see what's up. I ran some tests on Xcode using instruments but can't find any leaks.